# Batch xcopy YYYY/MM/DD HH/MM/SS

Tags: batch-file

Anybody know know how to edit a Batch for me if ok for that
i saw this somewhere which create a folder 12_07_2021_132247_19 etc but i like a more reader friendly like 2012-06-19 10:23:47, here the batch:

:while

```
set _my_datetime=%date%_%time%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime: =_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime::=%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:/=_%
set _my_datetime=%_my_datetime:.=_%


xcopy "FOLDER NAME" ".\Backup\%_my_datetime%\" /E/H/C/I
```

TIMEOUT 60

```
goto :while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need split the variables, becouse you can get value from date. try some thing like this:

```
xcopy "FOLDER NAME" ".\Backup\$(date +"%Y%m%d")\" /E/H/C/I
```

Can you provide us the feedback if this work for you?

Comment: why not? whats ir wrong?

Comment: ok i did replace from %_my_datetime%  TO  $(date +"%Y%m%d")   I then run the batch it did create a folder created $(date +md) but just this no YYYY MM DD etc

Comment: Thank for trying to help, it all ok as this what need   %date:~6,4%~%date:~3,2%~%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%~%time:~3,2%~%time:~6,2%   it was your idea that helped me with a search online,  Thank You